# ffmpeg compression takes a long time

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following ffmpeg command in a react-native project to convert and compress a mov-file to a mp4-file. The command works, but it takes +1m30sec to convert a clip of only 10 seconds. Before I did a simple copy (because afaik mov and mp4 have the same codecs), and this copy was pretty fast (almost instantaneous for a 10sec clip).

My command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

My previous command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

The preset `ultrafast` seems not to work with the first command.

Comment: Need to see the **complete** log from command 1.

Comment: `-preset ultrafast` only works with `-vcodec libx264`